# Spring+ LDAP integration

Tags: spring, ldap

I want to integrate LDAP in my spring application.

Requirement:- On request it should divert to my login page then ask for user/password. Then on  submit it should authentication from LDAP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a special project in Spring called [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html) for this purpose. The core functionality is built as a set of servlet API filters. There are multiple connectors for user's database (LDAP, DB, Active Directory, etc.) [Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-getting-started) you can see how to add a basic conf. Your conf may looks like this:

```
  <http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login />
    <logout />
  </http>
```

Note that I prefer [SpEL expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in) for security rules. And [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap) you can see how to add LDAP.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Along with that you also need other LDAP configuration like this

```
            <ldap-server url="ldap://localhost:10389/dc=example,dc=com" />


            <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
                erase-credentials="true">
                <ldap-authentication-provider
                    user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=people" group-search-base="ou=groups"
                    group-search-filter="(members={0})">
                </ldap-authentication-provider>
            </authentication-manager>
```